# Как выбрать значение из массива XML

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть `TextView` и `ImageView`

Не могу понять, как можно вывести значение из стринг и картинку. Значения в xml записаны как `stroka1`, `stroka2`, `stroka3`, а картинки имеют имена `img1,` `img2`, `img3`.

я имею:

```
int nomerstroki; // где значение для строки.
```

как мне подставить значение для вывода текста из `String` и `Drawable`? Два дня бьюсь, нашел что есть составление динамического запроса а ничего не понял...

код простой до ужаса, есть в лайоуте всего два элемента - текствью и имажевью, а в активити програмно указываются их значения:

```
TextView mDateName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_3);
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_3);
```

указывать для каждого значения много кода. поэтому КАК указать ЧТОБЫ

```
int get_num = ActivityUtil.getNum();

TextView mDateName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."text_"+get_num );
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id."img_"+get_num );
```

Конечно, с этим вариантом выводится просто текст `text_3` и `img_3`, а надо чтобы выводилось из стринга значение

Comment: а какой язык-то?
Добавьте его в метку вопроса.

Comment: Вы что-то перемудрили. Опишите задачу полнее. У вас три элемента и написание 6 строк вызывает затруднение? Или у вас список? и вы изобретаете ListView(RecyclerView)? Btw, в ресурсах можно задавать не только строки, но и массивы строк... И забудьте о конструировании идентификаторов, это костыльный путь.

Comment: Действительно, идентификаторы строк - это сплошное мучение... когда их много... А когда мало - то самое, потому как если есть массив - то его надо держать постоянно в голове либо создавать отдельный файл потому как постоянно подглядывать что записано в строке 329 надоедает...

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что R.id.text_3(и остальные) - это по сути константа типа int и динамически ее имя можно достать только через Reflection(знатоки, поправьте если не так), что будет гораздо более сложно, медленно и потенциально глючно, нежели если просто скопипастить код для всех необходимых элементов.

С другой стороны можно воспользоваться тэгами. Вот они как раз строковые и их имена можно генерировать динамически.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Вот нашел пример   "somevalue" + intVariable.toString()


for (Integer i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("somevalue" + i.toString(), "string", getPackageName());
    String value = (String) getResources().getText(id);
}   непонимаю как это работает

Comment: getIdentifier работает через Reflection. А это всегда медленно.

Comment: Не через reflection, но все равно медленно, да.

Answer (score 0):

Выход нашел пока такой - вполне быстро работает, однако, с эстетической части - много повторяющихся строк которые можно заменить одной, но пока не нашел подойдет и так.

```
    TextView text_kin_descr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_name);

    ImageView img_kin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_kin);

    //получение значения
    int kin_n = Actyvity.getK();

    //тут перебираем значения для 1 2 3 4 5 и тд
    if(kin_n == 1  ) {text_kin_descr.setText(string.kin1  );
    img_kin.setImageResource(drawable.img_kin1  );}
```

отличного всем дня!